# Book recommendation questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm aware of the necessities of a book recommendation question 'in order to not be considered opinion-based, and therefore closed, book recommendation questions must provide following information:'. <sub>[(tag)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/book-recommendation/info)</sub>

> - Broad area of study (default)
> - Scope of the book i.e. what topics should it cover. This should be a detailed list of topics that the OP is interested to study.
> - Level of the book i.e. should it be a suitable/intended for beginners or should it have detailed information suited for an advanced reader
>
> Other useful information includes why some books are specifically not deemed suitable.

But I saw a [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58525/text-book-recommendation-cell-molecular-biology-organic-chemistry), which is open despite not having the *'list of topics that the OP is interested to study'*.

I have been abstaining from asking a question about book recommendation in Evolution. The information I would provide if I ask won't involve the list of topics (as it is something I have no idea about; I have no preference and no syllabus for that). I would of course provide the level of the book and also what type of books I'm looking for (the books' approach).

So my question would be what types of deviations from this list are allowed in Biology Stackexchange?

P.S. I would like to know about **all** possible deviations so that it is useful for not only the case I have mentioned but others that may eventually arise.